# Chrome inspector - remote debugger - Clipboard is not enabled in hosted mode. Please inspect using chrome://inspect

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, opera, chromium, safari-web-inspector

I am using the remote debugger inspector by visiting for example:

http://localhost:9222/devtools/inspector.html?ws=localhost:9222/devtools/page/33767d5c-6abf-4c79-b8e7-d3b0c251fcaa

The inspector works other than not being able to copy within the element, **for copying xpath/sizzle selectors** for instance which is really **important**.

But on copy I am getting:

> Clipboard is not enabled in hosted mode. Please inspect using
>   chrome://inspect

I am remote debugging using an "external" inspector in google-chrome on linux.

I get the same error on **chromium-browser** as well.

What do I need to do **to enable clipboard** in Google Chrome?

Comment: visit chrome://inspect and select your application

Comment: @Rienk I had already been there. Doesn't work. Doesn't work to really select something other than click on a "link" inspect which upon copy gives me the same message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For those coming to this question, this annoyed me too so I have recently added support for copy operations in devtools in hosted mode, and, as the PR has been merged, it should just work in the latest version from Github.

Comment: Thank you, looking forward to trying this soon.

Comment: @momo Please remember to accept an answer if it works for you :)

Comment: @momomo Looks like I mistyped the user handle last time. Did this work out for you?